# System freezes after copying large files

Tags: kubuntu

So I've just copied 300gb of files from my external HDD to my laptop. After finishing my laptop is very slow, even after I've restarted the system. I've also noticed this problem on Fedora 30. Is this a Linux kernel issue? How can I solve this?

My laptop is running Kubuntu 19.04 (installed on SSD) with 8gb of RAM

Comment: How much space left after copying?

Comment: More than 500GB. The drive I'm copying to is a 1TB HDD, not the 128GB SSD

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution. Seems like KDE keeps remembering something from the previous session. Turning it off in Setting > Startup and Shutdown >  Desktop Session solves the issue.